# using logical core in program

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, multicore

Consider this code for setting thread affinity on a specific processor core:

```
pthread_attr_t attr;
cpu_set_t cpu;
CPU_ZERO(&cpu);
CPU_SET(CoreNumber, &cpu);
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr,sizeof(cpu_set_t),&cpu);
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr,SCHED_FIFO);
pthread_create(Thread,&attr,func,param);
```

My system has 4 physical cores, and each core has 2 logical cores. With this code when my core-number is 4, every thread runs on a separate core. For instance, thread 1 runs on core 0, thread 2 run on core 2, etc.

I want change the affinity such that two threads are ran on each core. For instance, thread 1 and thread 2 run on core 1's two logical cores, and thread 3 and thread 4 run on core 2's two logical cores.

Is that possible? How should I change above code?